# Custom ingress port and single-host mode with Eclipse Che on K8s

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, eclipse-che

I'm currently trying to upgrade my Eclipse Che installation from 6.19.0 to 7.7.1.

However due to the forced switch to K8s it made it a lot more difficult for me, as I have never used K8s before and the Che documentation is a little lacking since the upgrade as well.

So a disclaimer first; I'm a first time user of K8s (meaning Minikube or Microk8s) and I am having quite a hard time with it.

I got Che running with the provided `chectl` tool with both operator and helm installation types. However I'm still having two problems I just can't figure out.

1. I haven't been able to change the server type from multi-host to default-host or single-host. Even when I change it in the helm `values.yaml` it just get's ignored and starts in multi-host mode again.
2. I want to run Che on my existing development server and have already setup an nginx reverse proxy (on port `80` and `443`) for my running Nexus and Gitlab instances. So (if possible) I want to get Che behind that reverse proxy as well, however I just can't figure out how to change the ports of the k8s ingress controller. I even tried to change the host ports over the k8s dashboard, to no avail whatsoever. The nginx ingress server everytime wants to bind to port `80` and `443` and of course crashes every time because my nginx instance is already listening on those ports.

So do I have any chance to realize the setup I had before with only the docker installation on the new k8s deployment?

If it's not possible to get the installation behind my nginx proxy it would also be alright to just let it run on another port than `80` or `443`, however I just can't figure out how to change it.

Note: I'm trying to run it on a local k8s cluster with Minikube or Microk8s, so no "real" K8s cluster, but it made no difference on which I tried it.

Any help regarding this would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.